# Dijkstra with negative weights

Tags: algorithm, dijkstra

I'm trying to find an example of a directed graph with negative weights (no negative cycles) such that running dijksra on it will produce wrong results for **all** the vertices in the graph (except to the source node).

It isn't very hard to find an example to a graph where some of the results produced by dijkstra are wrong. but i can't find an example to a graph as described above, can anyone help me with it?

thanks.

Comment: The direct neighbors of the start vertex in the shortest path tree will always have correct distances. The worst you can get is a single correct vertex (plus start vertex). It is not possible to get no correct vertex.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose you have a graph G with three nodes A B and C.
Three arcs (A,B,5) , (A,C,2) , (B,c,-10)
and the source is A.

Now the shortest path from A to C will be 2 which is wrong.

It should be -5.